# Adobe Photoshop CS6

Tags: photoshop-cs5

What is the name of the tool on photo in Adobe Photoshop CS6, and how can I find it from my tools bar?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2yDY.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be the eraser which is between the history brush and gradient tools.

In any case, I recommend that you visit [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) as StackOverflow is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful